# Button spacing on UIToolbar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, nib

I am having a problem with the spacing of my button on my UIToolbar look at this images:

Here is my current out put it's a UIButton on a UIBarButtonItem and it's not the desired spacing that i am trying to do, i just set it on its nib file and they can't get any closer to each other.

[image]

and here is the output that i want.

[image]

Do you how can i set the spacing? by code or by its nib file?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using .xib file then you can use "Flexible space bar button Item or fixed space bar button item"

by using these between your toolbar items you can assign the space between them..
Its pretty handy and works good[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
NSMutableArray *baritem =[NSMutableArray array];
[baritem addObject:return_button];
[baritem addObject:SYSBARBUTTON(UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace, nil)];
[baritem addObject:preview];
[baritem addObject:SYSBARBUTTON(UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace, nil)];
[baritem addObject:play_button];
[baritem addObject:SYSBARBUTTON(UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace, nil)];
[baritem addObject:next];
[baritem addObject:SYSBARBUTTON(UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace, nil)];


#define SYSBARBUTTON(ITEM, SELECTOR) [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:ITEM target:self action:SELECTOR] autorelease]
```

by this i am setting space

Comment: should i put it on viewDidLoad?